# When a new thread is created does each individual thread make its own copy of the objects/methods() defined within the run() method?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

So I was watching a tutorial for multithreading in java and in the tutorial a class that extends the Thread class was created and the run() method was overridden, within the run method there is a call being made to the **`threadCountdown`** objects **`doCountDown()`** method example:

```
  class CountdownThread extends Thread{
    private Countdown threadCountdown;

    public CountdownThread(Countdown countdown){
        threadCountdown = countdown;
    }

    public void run(){
        threadCountdown.doCountdown();

    }
}
```

My question is that every time when a new thread is created from the code above will a separate copy be made of what is being called in the run() method, like for instance in the above code will a separate copy be made of the **`threadCountdown.doCountdown()`** method when ever a new thread is created? if so then can whole objects also be "copied" for a thread to use?

Comment: No. Java passes references to objects by value. And methods are not part of the state of an object.

Comment: You may be interested in learning about the concept of a *call stack*.

Comment: what do you mean by "copy of the method"?

Comment: by copy i mean two threads that each have their own individual copy/clone of a method

Comment: @TejusN that makes no sense. A method is a static piece of bytecode to execute. It's linked to the class, not to its instances. Copying methods makes no sense.

Comment: @JB Nizet thanks for the reply, I guess my confusion arises when multi threading comes into the picture. Does this mean that each time a thread is started whatever method that's called within a run() block will reference its classes instance methods copy and run that on its own thread stack?

Comment: Method code does NOT get "copied".

Answer (score 0):

In the above code snippet, **all the spawned threads will share the same object, present in the heap**.

---

There may arise a situation,wherein, in a concurrent environment, multiple threads may run on different CPUs (CPU core) and for faster execution, they may prefer to keep the object in the CPU cache instead of reading it from the main memory.
Eventually, this will invite other concurrency problems.

**For threads to create a separate copy, switch to using ThreadLocal variables.**